# Работа проверки на наличие элемента в массиве (PYTHON)

Tags: python

```
#На числовой прямой даны два отрезка: P=[10,29] и Q=[13,18]
#Укажите наибольшую возможную длину отрезка A, для которого
#выражение ((x∈A)<=(x∈P))or(x∈Q) тоджественно истинно,
#то есть принимает значение 1 при любых целых неотрицательных x?

def f(x,A):
    P=[i for i in range(10,30)]
    Q=[i for i in range(13,18)]
    return ((x in A) <= (x in P)) or (x in Q)

for A in range(0,500):
    OK=True
    for x in range(0,500):
        if not f(x,A):
            OK=False
            break
    if OK:
        print(A)
```

В функции отказывает работать проверка наличии элемента в массиве. Выдаёт ошибку: `argument of type 'int' is not iterable'`. Подскажите, как переписать функцию, чтобы проверка заработала?

Comment: У вас `A` это число

Answer (score 0):

В данной задачи мы должны найти А (отрезок) на котором любое для любого х верно выражение ((x∈A)<=(x∈P))or(x∈Q). Вот мое решение

```
def f(x):
    p = {'min': 10, 'max': 29}
    q = {'min': 13, 'max': 18}
    value_ = (p['min'] <= x <= p['max']) or (q['min'] <= x <= q['max'])
    return value_

a = []
for i in range(1, 500):
    iter = f(i)
    if iter == True:
        a.append(i)
a.sort()
print(a)
otrezok = {}
y1 = otrezok['min'] = a[0]
y2 = otrezok['max'] = a[len(a)-1]

print(f'Наибольшая длина отрезка А = [{y1}, {y2}]')
```